# Make difference between two date picker fields using jQuery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hi Friends I am working on Hotel booking form and getting stuck on **date-picker** function. There are two field first to get **"Check in date"** and second is for **"Checkout date"**. I want that there is at least one day difference (or same day) between **"Check in date"** & **"Checkout date"**. If user select checkout date first like if user select **"01/jan/2014"** for checkout and after that user go to check-in date then he selects **"4/jan/2014"** for check-in which is wrong you cant check in before checkout I want when user selects **"4/jan/2014"** for check-in then checkout date will update **"4/jan/2014"** for check-out and user unable to selects previous dates for checkout

You can find my code here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt8yM/)

**HTML**

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Check in date <input type="text" name="ww" size="30" id="1" class="nameBook"/>
Checkout date <input type="text" name="ww" size="30" id="2" class="nameBook"/>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".nameBook" ).datepicker();
});
```

Please help me guys .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your case what you need to know about is [**date-range**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range), here I was modified your code as below to work on

```
 $(function () {
     $("#1").datepicker({
         onClose: function (selectedDate) {
             $("#2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
         }
     });
     $("#2").datepicker({
         defaultDate: "+1w",
         onClose: function (selectedDate) {
             $("#1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
         }
     });
 });
```

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xt8yM/1/)